# Path variable to use in data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

i have a problem with tab title setting. Before is was always the same title which is set in index.html

Now i would like to have another title in some components and wanted to and using data routes for it, but is it possible to take :userId from path directly in data?

```
{ path: 'users/user-details/:userId', component: UserDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data : {title:'User - '}}
```

So the tab title should look like this

> User - 1234 or User - :userId

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the document title dinamically based on the route params.

You can use [Title](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title#set-the-document-title) service to achieve that.

Register it on the module providers:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [Title],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Inject it on your component:

```
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private title: Title, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Then retrieve data from the activated route and pass it to the setTitle method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const title: string = route.snapshot.data.title;
    const userId: string = route.snapshot.params.userId;
    this.title.setTitle(title + userId);
}
```

In this example I'm using the route snapshot but you might want to subscribe to the route observables instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, i was wondering if i can avoid injecting title in every component i need it, but seems there is no option like i thought there could be.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! try to do something like this:

In your .ts component:

```
...
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.css'],
})
export class YourComponent {

  id: string = '';
 
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('userID');
    console.log(this.id);
  }

 }
```

That was if your userID is not going to change.
If it could be changed, then you can try this other approach, changing the constructor:

```
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params.get('userID');
      console.log(this.id);
    });
```